# Нужен ли мягкий знак в слове?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, глаголы, сказуемые

Нужен ли мягкий знак в слове «вернуться»?

1. «Счастье в моментах, что не вернуться».
2. «Счастье в моментах, что не вернутся».

Какой из вариантов правильный? Нужен только ответ, верное написание цитаты. Чтобы смысл был такой: «Счастье в моментах, которые уже не вернуть».

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно без мягкого знака: «Счастье в моментах, что не вернутся».

Слово ***что*** здесь заменяет слово ***которые*** и является подлежащим.
От него нужно задать вопрос: *которые (= они, моменты) что сдела**ют**? – не верн**ут**ся*.
А к глаголу в неопределённой форме задаётся вопрос *что сдела**ть**? – не верну**ть**ся*.